# open port for iis

Tags: iis, networking, webserver, port, firewall

folks I want to know how I can open port for iis.I have also tired from firewall to open port but I can't it's seem I am missing some thing actually i have site (example on port) 7895 in my local I can access it by type localhost:7895 in browser or 192.168.1.1:7895 (local ip) but want to open it through over net for example my external ip is 119.155.116.102 so 119.155.116.102:7895 how I can do it? Yes is there any problem in router I mean I need to open  or some function in router to open port?

thanks for answere!

Answer (score -1):

Yes in most cases you need to open port in your router first (check your NAT settings section), and then setup IIS site binding to 7895 port

Comment: Hi thanks now it's nice I open my port but still haven't see webpage from this port I also have bind iis with that port! what should i do i have check from http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ that's my port is open but still don't see website in my local

Comment: also try to check your windows firewall settings it could block outbound connection

Comment: yes i check but still don't show me my web page is there any details tutorial or article to make local pc to server kind? Google drive me crazy bit!

Comment: when you replace your ip address in IIS binding to localhost is your site working? (also please make sure that you using IIS not VS Dev server

Comment: About tutorial, I read good beginner tutorial in Steven Sanderson book "Freeman A. Sanderson S. -  Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework" 3rd Edition - 2011 (it is an excellent asp .net mvc book btw) also you can try http://learn.iis.net/ for more specific information. But it is weird that your site doesn't showed up. also try different port like 8080 or even 80

Comment: know I mean how I can make my ports viewable for internet or external kind tutorials!